# Salesforce SOQL Trimming the field

Tags: salesforce, soql, salesforce-service-cloud

I am callling the SOQL query through REST API from php.  I am searching for the phone number using the below SOQL query.  I want to trim the mobilephone in where clause.  I tried `MobilePhone.trim()` and `trim(MobilePhone)`  it's not working.  How can I do it?

```
Select FirstName FROM Contact WHERE  MobilePhone = '04123456789'
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can anyone help me out regarding this thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no ability to use 'trim' function in 'where' condition of SOQL.